# HTML5 / kineticJS "getIntersection" function implementation (Canvas Game)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, collision-detection, kineticjs

I am trying to recreate the game http://www.sinuousgame.com/ and started studying **html5 canvas** and **kineticJS**.

As you can see, My **Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/p9fnq/5/ 
(You could try commenting my checkCollide function definition and its calling,to see my output)

**(New fiddle at bottom of post)**

```
//The working player code
var LimitedArray = function(upperLimit) {
    var storage = [];

    // default limit on length if none/invalid supplied;
    upperLimit = +upperLimit > 0 ? upperLimit : 100;

    this.push = function(item) {
        storage.push(item);
        if (storage.length > upperLimit) {
            storage.shift();
        }
        return storage.length;
    };

    this.get = function(flag) {
        return storage[flag];
    };

    this.iterateItems = function(iterator) {
        var flag, l = storage.length;
        if (typeof iterator !== 'function') {
            return;
        }
        for (flag = 0; flag < l; flag++) {
            iterator(storage[flag]);
        }
    };
};

var tail = new LimitedArray(50);

var flag = 0, jincr = 0;
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    listening: true
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    listening: true
});
stage.add(layer);
var player = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    radius: 6,
    fill: 'cyan',
    stroke: 'black',
    draggable: true
});
var line = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: [],
    stroke: 'cyan',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    lineCap: 'round',
    lineJoin: 'round'
});
layer.add(line);
layer.add(player);

// move the circle with the mouse
stage.getContent().addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    player.position(stage.getPointerPosition());
    var obj = {
        x: stage.getPointerPosition().x,
        y: stage.getPointerPosition().y
    };

    tail.push(obj);
    var arr = [];
    tail.iterateItems(function(p) {
        arr.push(p.x, p.y);
    });
    line.points(arr);
});

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var noOfEnemies = 200;
var enemyArmada = new Array();


createEnemy();

function createEnemy() {
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfEnemies; i++) {
        var enemy = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: Math.random() * window.innerWidth,
            y: Math.random() * window.innerHeight,
            radius: 4.5 + 1.5 * Math.random(),
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black'
        });
        enemy.speedX = enemy.speedY = (0.5 + Math.random() * 50);
        enemyArmada.push(enemy);
        layer.add(enemy);
    }
}

var checkCollide = function() {
    var collided = stage.getIntersections(stage.getPointerPosition());
    if (typeof collided !== 'Kinetic.Shape') {
        console.log("not shape");
    }
    else {
        console.log("BOOOM!!!");
    }
};


var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
    checkCollide();
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfEnemies; i++) {
        var e = enemyArmada[i];
        e.position({
            x: e.position().x - e.speedX * (frame.timeDiff / 400),
            y: e.position().y + e.speedY * (frame.timeDiff / 400)
        });

        if (e.position().y < 0 || e.position().x < 0) {
            e.position({
                x: (Math.random() * (window.innerWidth + 600)),
                y: -(Math.random() * window.innerHeight)
            });
        }
    }
    }, layer);
anim.start();
```

This is the error i finally ended up with:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

I need this error to be rectified plus collision to be detected.(Show the console  messages as i have written in the checkCollide function).

Can anyone help me out with this??

**EDIT:** Have rectified the error,but collision detection not working.
New Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p9fnq/8/

Answer (score 0):

Your check collide function has a simple flaw in it, if the pointer (cursor/mouse) is not on the screen it will fail as the pointer position is null. Rather than the pointer position, you may want to check the player position, since the pointer position is tied to the player position.

http://jsfiddle.net/p9fnq/8/

```
var checkCollide = function() {
    var position = stage.getPointerPosition(); //pointer position
    if(position == null)
        position = player.position(); //player position
    if(position == null)
        position = {x:0,y:0}; // fallback
    var collided = stage.getIntersection(position); 
    console.log(position);
    if (typeof collided !== 'Kinetic.Shape') {
        console.log("not shape");
    }
    else {
        console.log("BOOOM!!!");
    }
};
```

See updated fiddle.

Comment: Hey,thnx the error seems to be rectified.
But the collision is still not being detected.
(console.log("BOOOM!!!");)

Comment: I solved your original problem, please close this question and create a new one with your collision detection problem.